# Referencing child class instance type in parent class method

Tags: typescript

```
class Axis {
    linkedAxisX: AxisX[]
    link(axisB: AxisX) {
        this.linkedAxisX.push((AxisX)this)
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass a child class instance AxisX of my superclass Axis in my link method in Axis. How do I make this not give me a compile time error on `this` passed as parameter?

Comment: What compile time error are you getting? Please create [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem you are having clearly.

Comment: To push an `this` to an array typed as `AxisX[]`, then `this` must be of type `AxisX`. Which means that can only work when called from the `AxisX` subclass, which means that's where the method belongs. If you called `link` from an insance of `Axis` then `this` would be `Axis` and this would be invalid. If you elaborate with a more complete example then I can probably help more. But as is I can only identify the problem and not help you solve it,.

Comment: @AlexWayne that's along the lines of what i was thinking.  still compiles and works though.